# ModelMapper configuration errors

Tags: spring-boot, modelmapper

I have a JSON :

```
{
    "signatureOptions": {
        "signatureType": "string",
        "digestAlgorithmName": "string",
        "signaturePackagingType": "string",
        "documentType": "string"
       },
    "pdfSignatureOptions": {
        "signatureTextColor": integerValue,
        "signatureTextFontSize": floatValue,
        "fontFamily": "string",
        "fontStyle": "string",
        "signatureImageContent": "string",
        "signatureText": "string",
        "signaturePosX": floatValue,
        "signaturePosY": floatValue,
        "signaturePage": integerValue
       },
       "enableArchive": false,
       "archiverNames": [
        "string"
       ],
    "toSignContent": "String"
}
```

I created the following POJOs

```
@Getter @Setter
public class SignatureOptions {
    private String signatureType;
    private String digestAlgorithmName;
    private String signaturePackagingType;
    private String documentType;

    // constructor
}

@Getter @Setter
public class PdfSignatureOptions {
    private int signatureTextColor;
    private float signatureTextFontSize;
    private String fontFamily;
    private String fontStyle;
    private String signatureImageContent;
    private String signatureText;
    private float signaturePosX;
    private float signaturePosY;
    private int signaturePage;

    // constructor
}

@Getter @Setter
public class DocumentToSignRestRequest {
    private SignatureOptions signatureOptions = new SignatureOptions();
    private PdfSignatureOptions pdfSignatureOptions = new PdfSignatureOptions();
    private boolean enableArchive;
    private ArrayList< Object > archiverNames = new ArrayList <>();
    private String toSignContent;

    // constructor
}
```

In my controller I have a @PostMapping method I try to retrieve the DocumentToSignRestRequest :

```
@PostMapping(
    value="/sign",
    consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE },
    produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE }
)
public DocumentRest getDocumentSigned(@RequestBody DocumentToSignRestRequest  documentToSignRestRequest) throws Exception {
    // instanciate empty return object
    DocumentRest returnValue = new DocumentRest();

    // Map the documentToSignRestRequest with a DTO Object
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    DocumentDto documentDto = modelMapper.map(documentToSignRestRequest, DocumentDto.class);

    // Call the documentService layer and assign the return to a new DOcumentDto
    DocumentDto signedDocument = documentService.signDocument(documentDto);
    returnValue = modelMapper.map(signedDocument, DocumentRest.class);
    // return a rest object with signedDocument values
    return returnValue;
}
```

and pass it to a DocumentDto class by using a ModelMapper : DocumentDto documentDto = modelMapper.map(documentToSignRestRequest, DocumentDto.class);

The different properties of this class have the same name as in the different class that are composing the class i want to map.

```
@Getter @Setter
public class DocumentDto implements Serializable {

    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6835192601898364280L;

    // document information from DocumentRest
    private String documentName;
    private String documentPath;
    private boolean isDocumentSigned;
    // SignatureOptions values
    private String signatureType;
    private String digestAlgorithmName;
    private String signaturePackagingType;
    private String documentType;
    // PdfSignatureOptionsObject values
    private int signatureTextColor;
    private float signatureTextFontSize;
    private String fontFamily;
    private String fontStyle;
    private String signatureImageContent;
    private String signatureText;
    private float signaturePosX;
    private float signaturePosY;
    private int signaturePage;

    private boolean enableArchive;
    private ArrayList< Object > archiverNames = new ArrayList <>();
    private String toSignContent;
}
```

When I use postman I obtain an error message :

ModelMapper configuration errors:\r\n\r\n1) The destination property com.app.ws.certeuropews.shared.dto.DocumentDto.setSignatureType() matches multiple source property hierarchies:\n\n\tcom.app.ws.certeuropews.ui.model.request.DocumentToSignRestRequest.getSignatureOptions()/

What would be the solution for this issue. I was looking at the ModelMapper guide and I'm wondering.. http://modelmapper.org/examples/projection/#example-1

Answer (score 0):

I didn't correctly set the DTO layer :

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class DocumentDto implements Serializable {

    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6835192601898364280L;

    // document information from DocumentRest
    private String documentName;
    private String documentPath;
    private boolean isDocumentSigned;
    // SignatureOptions values
    private SignatureOptionsDto signatureOptionsDto;
    // PdfSignatureOptionsObject values
    private PdfSignatureOptionsDto pdfSignatureOptionsDto;

    private boolean enableArchive;
    private ArrayList< Object > archiverNames = new ArrayList <>();
    private String toSignContent;
}
```